# Get string of nested object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an object that looks like this:

```js
public serviceTable: Services[] = [
  { 1: { service: 'Service 1', description: 'Lorem Ipsum', serviceIsMandatory: true, serviceIsDisabled: true, price: 100, hourlyRate:100, hours: 5} },
  { 2: { service: 'Service 2', description: 'Lorem Ipsum', serviceIsMandatory: true, serviceIsDisabled: true, price: 100, hourlyRate:100, hours: 5} },
  { 3: { service: 'Service 3', description: 'Lorem Ipsum', serviceIsMandatory: true, serviceIsDisabled: true, price: 100, hourlyRate:100, hours: 5} }
];
```

Now in HTML, I want to output the values of `service` in my table.

```js
<table mat-table [dataSource]="serviceTable" #matTableService class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="service">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Service</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element[1].service }}</td>
  </ng-container>
```

Well, `element[1].service` works fine and outputs the string `Service 1` but this is static and I want to make it dynamic.

I have also tried it with `{{element.key | json }}` but that outputs nothing. So how can I make it dynamic?

Comment: you will need to loop over the `serviceTable` array making a `td` element for each item in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `let i = index;` to iterate here.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="serviceTable" #matTableService class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="service">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Service</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;">{{ element[i].service }}</td>
  </ng-container>
```

Comment: Since `i` starts with 0 and the IDs of my object start with 1, I have received an error. I have now changed the IDs of my object and that works great. Thank you!

Comment: You can also give `{{ element[i+1].service }}` in that case.